# The wkhtmltopdf process on Apache never ends

Tags: php, apache, wkhtmltopdf

I have a PHP script to generate a PDF with wkhtmltopdf and xvfb (to simulate X server).

Using command line, there is no problem.

When this script is incorporated into my website, wkhtmltopdf never stops.

I am using

- Apache 2.4
- PHP 5.4
- wkhtmltopdf 0.11.0 rc1

What can cause this issue?

Comment: make sure the paths are absolute.

Comment: Like Gung Foo said, make sure the path is absolute. More importantly: make sure your html file ends in .html. Otherwise, wkhtmltopdf will fail silently. This has given me a headache some time ago.

Comment: I check, the path is absolute. I stop a cron job that killing wkhtmltopdf. Now It never stop.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with a specific version of wkhtmltopdf.
See this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807438/php-shell-exec-hangs-when-using-wkhtmltopdf?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807438/php-shell-exec-hangs-when-using-wkhtmltopdf?rq=1)